# Display form for each product in this page and store form data in database

Tags: magento2, collection

Step 1: Here with each product, I want to display a form and store data in the Database.

Step 2: Get all the data with product id and order id in the Admin Panel.

My module PHP file Code

```
<?php
namespace Softadroit\Prescription\Block;

class Prescription extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_orderFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Get quote object associated with cart. By default it is current customer session quote
     *
     * @return \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote
     */
    public function getQuoteData()
    {
        $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote();
        if (!$this->hasData('quote')) {
            $this->setData('quote', $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote());
        }
        return $this->_getData('quote');
    }
}
?>
```

And this is my .phtml file code

```
<?php
// Get all visible items in cart
$quote = $block->getQuoteData();

foreach($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $_item) {
    echo 'Name: '.$_item->getName().'<br/>';
    echo 'Quantity: '.$_item->getQty().'<br/>';
    echo 'Price: $'.$_item->getPrice().'<br/>';
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

Comment: Describe the requirement in some more detail, what you are trying and what is the issue into that one?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya I want to add a form to collect some data from the customer before checkout. So I have to display form with the individual product added to the checkout. And store that form in the database. I am new to Magento so I don't know how it works

Comment: Then have you make any thing?

Comment: No I am looking for, how it can be done

Comment: For each product, what information you want to take from customer? And from that how much you need to save?

Comment: I have to collect data like: age, height, weight and more from customer. And want to save it in new table in database.

Comment: @ArunKumar in which page you want form in cart page or product page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below Code for phtml file:

```
<?php
// Get all visible items in cart
$quote = $block->getQuoteData();
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
?>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <form name="addData" method="post" id="addData" class="form" action="<?php echo $this->getFormAction(); ?>" data-hasrequired="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('* Required Fields')) ?>" data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'>
        <?php foreach($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $_item) { 
            $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($_item->getProductId());
            $customerId = $block->getLoggedinCustomerId();
            //echo $product->getPrescription(); //die();
            $is_priscription = $product->getData('prescription');
            if($is_priscription != "" && $is_priscription == '5431'){  // change prescription option id here ?>
            <fieldset class="fieldset">
                <legend class="legend"><span>Add Prescription: <?php echo $_item->getName(); ?></span></legend>
                <fieldset class="fieldset row">
                    <div class="fields col-md-6">
                        <div class="field name required">
                            <label class="label" for="name"><span>Name</span></label>
                            <div class="control">
                            <input name="name[]" id="name" title="Name" value="" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field required">
                            <label class="label" for="age"><span>Age</span></label>
                            <div class="control">
                                <input name="age[]" id="Age" title="Age" class="input-text" type="int" data-validate="{required:true}"> Years</input>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field required">
                            <label class="label" for="height"><span>Height</span></label>
                            <div class="control">
                                <input name="height[]" id="Height" title="Height" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"> FT</input>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field required">
                            <label class="label" for="weight"><span>Weight</span></label>
                            <div class="control">
                                <input name="weight[]" id="Weight" title="Weight" class="input-text" type="int" data-validate="{required:true}"> KG</input>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field required">
                            <label class="label" for="gender"><span>Gender</span></label>
                            <select name="subject_gender[]">
                            <option>---Select Gender--</option>
                            <option value="male">Male</option>
                            <option value="female">Female</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>                      
                        <!--<div class="field date required">
                            <label class="label" for="publish_date"><span>Publish Date</span></label>
                            <div class="control">
                                <input type="text" name="publish_date" id="datepicker"  data-validate="{required:true}">
                            </div>
                        </div>-->
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset style="display:none">             
                    <div class="field required" style="display:none">
                    <label class="label" for="product_id"><span></span></label>
                        <select name="product_id[]">
                        <option value="<?php echo $_item->getProductId(); ?>"><?php echo $_item->getProductId(); ?></option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field required" style="display:none">
                    <label class="label" for="customer_id"><span></span></label>
                        <select name="customer_id[]">
                        <option value="<?php echo $customerId; ?>"><?php echo $customerId; ?></option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </fieldset>
            <?php } } ?>
        <div class="actions-toolbar">
            <div class="primary">
                <button type="submit" class="action submit primary" title="Save"><span>Save</span></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(["jquery", "mage/calendar"], function($){
    $("#datepicker").calendar({
        showsTime: false,
        dateFormat: "M/d/Y",
        yearRange: "-120y:c+nn",
        maxDate: "-1d", changeMonth: true, changeYear: true})
    });
</script>
```

Block php file

```
<?php
namespace Softadroit\Prescription\Block;

class Prescription extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_orderFactory;
    
    protected $_customerSession;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory $customerSession,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession->create();;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
    
    
    public function getFormAction()
    {   
        return $this->getUrl('prescription/index/save', ['_secure' => true]);  
    }
    
    public function getLoggedinCustomerId() {
        if ($this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            return $this->_customerSession->getId();
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    public function getQuoteData()
    {
        $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote();
        if (!$this->hasData('quote')) {
            $this->setData('quote', $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote());
        }
        return $this->_getData('quote');
    }
}
?>
```